# Implementation of BEGAN (Boundary Equilibrium GAN) Using CNTK Python API

Tags: python, deep-learning, cntk

I found an implementation for BEGAN using CNTK.
(https://github.com/2wins/BEGAN-cntk)

This uses MNIST dataset instead of Celeb A which was used in the original paper.
However, I don't understand the result images, which looks quite deterministic:
[Output images of the trained generator (iter: 30000)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5xSQ.png)

For different noise samples, I expect different outputs come from it. But it doesn't do that regardless of any hyper-parameters. Which part of the code does make the problem?

Please explain it.

Comment: `BEGAN-cntk` works well after 1 year. There might have been a problem in CNTK.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your model might be getting stuck in a particular mode. One idea would be to add an additional condition on the class labels. Conditional GANs have been proposed to overcome such limitations.

http://www.foldl.me/uploads/2015/conditional-gans-face-generation/paper.pdf

This is an idea that would be worth exploring.

Comment: I do not understand that the software used in the implementation has changed and the results have varied. The original network model for CelebA also does not work for the dataset, which is presented in the paper.

Answer (score 0):

Use higher gamma (for example gamma=1 or 1.3, more than 1 actually). Then it will improve certainly but would not make it perfect. Take enough iterations like 200k.

Please look at the paper carefully. It says the parameter gamma controls diversity.

One of the results that I obtained is [image].

I'm also looking for the best parameters and best results, but haven't yet.

Comment: Are the above images obtained on CNTK? Unfortunately, your advice does not affect results.

Comment: @David
No. I used BEGAN by Heumi (github).